# Como habilitar no Rails suporte a múltiplas conexões abertas ao bando de dados?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Utilizo PostgreSQL em minha API e caso meu GUI (Navicat) esteja aberto acessando a base de dados da aplicação e tente rodar o comando `db:drop db:create db:migrate db:seed` obtenho o erro abaixo:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::ObjectInUse: ERROR:  database "platform_development" is being accessed by other users
```

Somente com o GUI (Navicat) fechado consigo efetivar o comando. É possível habilitar suporte a múltiplas conexões simultâneas sem ter que ficar fechando o GUI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está no PostgreSQL!

Para resolver é preciso finalizar a conexão antes de criar uma nova. Felizmente é possível criar uma `task` para isso e invocar o fechamento da conexão através de gatilhos no Rails.

Apesar de não ser uma tarefa complexa de se fazer manualmente, a [gem pgreset](https://github.com/falconed/pgreset) encapsula a lógica necessária, deixando simples a adição deste recurso:

```
group :development, :test do
  ...
  gem 'pgreset', '~> 0.1.1'
end
```

Feito isso é possível ter o GUI (Navicat) aberto enquanto você roda o comando `db:drop db:create db:migrate db:seed`.